# Wordpress PHP commented out when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-get-contents

The following wordpress shortcode behaves correctly when placed within `single.php`

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="13" title="KB EN Contact"]' ); ?>
```

However, when placing this within another file and using:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("en-contact.php", 1);?>
```

the php is displayed as commented out HTML. The surrounding HTML elements are correctly displayed.

```
<section id="contact-after-post" class="clearfix">
    <h3 id="contact-after-post-title">Didn't find what you were looking for?</h3>
      <div id="contact-after-post-number">
      </div>
      <div id="contact-after-post-number-click">
        <div id="number-left">
        </div>
        <div id="number-right">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="contact-after-post-form">
<!--?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="13" title="KB EN Contact"]' ); ?-->
      </div>
</section>
```

Why has this happened? Why does the behaviour change with external files?

Comment: Hint: there are [better ways of including template parts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) in WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of file_get_contents(), you can try include() function.

CODE :

```
<?php include("en-contact.php");  ?>
```